# How do I get a curve point on a line?

Tags: python, opencv

i want to detect all corner and start , end point on line. i can detect start and end point but curve can't detect. this is my code

```
from scipy.ndimage import generic_filter

def lineEnds(P):
    return 255 * ((P[4]==255) and np.sum(P)==510)

 image = cv2.imread("./dataset/test.jpg" , cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
 result = generic_filter(image , lineEnds, (3, 3))
```

image = [image]

result = [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect corners with the `OpenCV` too

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('./test.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Detect corners in the image
corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, 500, qualityLevel=0.01, minDistance=20)

for c in corners:
    x, y = c.reshape(2)
    print(x, y)
    # draw a circle around the detected corner
    cv2.circle(image, (x, y), radius=4, color=(0, 255, 120), thickness=2)

cv2.imshow("Result", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Result:**

[image]

**For more details please check these docs:**

[Shi-Tomasi Corner Detector](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d8c/tutorial_py_shi_tomasi.html)

[Harris Corner Detection](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d0d/tutorial_py_features_harris.html)

Comment: The `goodFeaturesToTrack` in this example is a shovel used as a guiding tool for planes to land. It might work, but not really intended to be used that way.

Comment: @Croolman,  I would be pleased to have another answer.